# Power consumption - Matebook X Pro

Tags: nvidia, graphics, battery

Edit: Based on a suggestion in the comments, I Switched from Nvidia-390 driver to Nouveau and discharge rate went from ~10w to ~5w.

I have a core i7 Matebook X Pro.
It lasts about 6 hours on battery.
This is a fresh install of Budgie 18.04.

powertop shows: The battery reports a discharge rate of 10.6 W

This is with absolutely no other apps started (except Tilix terminal to run powertop).

I have other people telling me they average about 5W discharge rate.

I have installed the nvidia-390 drivers and the discharge rate is about the same whether I'm using Nvidia GPU or Intel integrated (620) graphics.

It almost seems as if somehow the Nvidia side is still enabled?
Any thoughts on what else I can do or what other info I can give to help diagnose?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: It's entirely possible that NVIDIA settings is not actually powering down the NVIDIA card.  Have you tried using the Nouveau driver instead? NVIDIA's linux driver is primarily focused at computation performance, not power consumption or dynamic mode setting like their Windows driver can do.  The Nouveau driver has better power management, but does have lower performance for games.

Comment: I'll switch back and see what results I'm getting.
I did notice that powertop was reporting:

Power est.    Usage     Device name
  7.92 W     99.0%        Display backlight

That is just for the backlight even when I have it at the very lowest level. That seems like a lot. I'm wondering if that isn't just for the backlight or if it is also the graphics card contributing.

Comment: Switched back to Nouveau and it dropped to ~ 5.5w.
AND the Display backlight pretty much disappeared from the list.
Brilliant.  Thanks so much for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What helped me to reduce the discharge rate from 7.44W to 5.59W for Matebook X Pro on Ubuntu 19.04 (driver=i915) was running powertop:

```
sudo powertop
```

And when I switched to the last section Tunables with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, there was one parameter marked as `bad`:

```
>> Bad   Runtime PM for PCI Device NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150]
```

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on it switched power control of the graphic card to `auto`.

```
>> echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control';
```

Bam! - 2,5 hours added to battery life time:

```
The estimated remaining time is 10 hours, 0 minutes
```

Comment: Yeah.. the issues I was having were on 18.04. Turns out that it was indeed leaving the Nvidia GPU loaded. 

I've since upgraded to 19.04 and the driver switching works great. I can either use Nvidia OR I can set it to use Intel and it actually honors that. My battery life on the Intel setting is easily 8-9 hours now.

powertop on top of 19.04 also identified a few more things that dropped the watt drain. So your tip is indeed correct.. but I tried powertop on the 18.04 and it didn't help.. (because the NVIDIA GPU was still active all the time).

Comment: Which driver did you finally stayed with on 19.04? After some more playing with it I can't seem to find a setup which would automatically offload GPU when not needed.

Comment: Specifically it is using nvidia-driver-418.

It won't 'automatically' switch. You have to bring up the 'NVIDIA X Server Settings' app and toggle it to Intel GPU or NVIDIA, then log out and back in.

Comment: Well, apparently that's not how it is supposed to be working - when I open up nvidia settings on desktop (16.04) I can see power levels being switched depending on opened applications (adaptive mode). For new linux kernel on the notebook it is not the case.